# How do I update the parent of a nested route when child route is updated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my application, it is possible to manage a list of articles.  The sequence of operations is:

1. The list of articles will render on the home page.
2. Clicking on an article in the list will cause a nested view to appear with the contents of the selected article.  When this happens, the article list remains in view, so the user sees the full list of articles on the left and the selected article on the right.
3. The user can then click an EDIT link, which puts the ArticleView in edit mode.
4. The user edits the ArticleName and ArticleText and submits the change.
5. A function in ArticleView handles the submission by making an API call to edit the article on the backend, and then puts the ArticleView back in read only mode.

During this last step, router.push is called to refresh the view.  My goal is for the ArticlesView to update so that it includes the new values for the article.  However, this is not happening.

Here are some sections of the code:

***Routes***

```
  {
    path: "/articlesview",
    name: "ArticlesView",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "articles" */ "../views/Home.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/articleview/:ArticleID/:edit",
        name: "ArticleView",
        props: true,
        component: () => 
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "article" */ "../components/Article.vue")
      }
    ]
  }
```

***ArticlesView***

```
        <div v-for="Article in Articles" :key="Article.ArticleID">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'ArticleView',
                                params: {
                                  'ArticleID': Article.ArticleID,
                                  'edit': false
                                }}"> {{Article.ArticleName}}</router-link>
        </div>
```

***ArticleView code that tries to refresh the page***

```
    this.$router.push({
                  name: 'ArticleView',
                  params: {
                    'ArticleID': Number(this.Article.ArticleID),
                    'edit': Boolean(false)
                    }
```

I have read through the Vue.js reactivity material on the Vue.js Web site, but I am unable to determine if this is intended behavior or not.  As you can see, I did take care to include a key in the v-for of the ArticlesView to help Vue with updating that structure.

How can achieve the desired behavior?